# wrap the existing code of a method in a try-finally block

Tags: java, try-catch, java-bytecode-asm, javaagents

I am new to ASM and I used the below code to put the try-finally inside method  And its working fine but I want  `super.visitInsn(opcode)` inside finally block. How can I achieve this? I tried many times but I'm unable to understand how to implement it

```
  private Label m_currentBeginLabel;
  private boolean m_isInOriginalCode = true;

  protected void execBeforeMethodCode() {
    // Code at the beginning of the method and not in a try block
  }

  protected void execVisitTryBlockBegin() {
    // Code at the beginning of each try block
  }

  protected void execVisitFinallyBlock() {
    // Code in each finally block
  }

  @Override
  public void visitCode() {
      super.visitCode();
    try {
         System.out.println("Inside my visit try block code.."); 
      m_isInOriginalCode = false;
      execBeforeMethodCode();
      beginTryFinallyBlock();
    }
    finally {
      m_isInOriginalCode = true;
    }
  }

  protected void beginTryFinallyBlock() {
    m_currentBeginLabel = new Label();
    visitLabel(m_currentBeginLabel);
    execVisitTryBlockBegin();
  }

  @Override
  public void visitInsn(int opcode) {
    if (m_isInOriginalCode && isReturnOpcode(opcode)){
      try {
        m_isInOriginalCode = false;
        completeTryFinallyBlock();

        super.visitInsn(opcode);

        beginTryFinallyBlock();
      }
      finally {
        m_isInOriginalCode = true;
      }
    }
    else {
      super.visitInsn(opcode);
    }
  }

  protected void completeTryFinallyBlock() {
    Label l1 = new Label();
    visitTryCatchBlock(m_currentBeginLabel, l1, l1, null);
    Label l2 = new Label();
    visitJumpInsn(GOTO, l2);
    visitLabel(l1);
    // visitFrame(Opcodes.F_SAME1, 0, null, 1, new Object[] { "java/lang/Throwable" });
    visitVarInsn(ASTORE, 1);

    execVisitFinallyBlock();

    visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 1);
    super.visitInsn(ATHROW);
    visitLabel(l2);
    // visitFrame(Opcodes.F_SAME, 0, null, 0, null);

    execVisitFinallyBlock();
  }

   protected boolean isReturnOpcode(int opcode) {
     return opcode >= Opcodes.IRETURN && opcode <= Opcodes.RETURN;
   }
```

Comment: don't post a link to an external page, put your code here as formatted code (in your question, not in a comment), be clear about what you tried, and why it doesn't work. it doesn't compile? you get a runtime error? error message?

Comment: Okay I will post  my code here

Comment: I got -> public String message() {
    Result.agentReport.startHere();
    try {
        // existing code
      Result.agentReport.stopHere("MYAPP", "con/Hello", "RESULT");
      return "Hello World";
    } finally {}
  }
  But I want -> public String message() {
    Result.agentReport.startHere();
    try {
     // existing code
      return "Hello World";
    } 
   finally {
           Result.agentReport.stopHere("MYAPP", "con/Hello", "RESULT");
        }
  }

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embed the existing code of a method in a try-finally block (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28415896/embed-the-existing-code-of-a-method-in-a-try-finally-block-2)